# In a complete space $X$ is every $x \in X$ the limit of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x \not\in \{x_n\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be a complete metric space. Then for any point $x \in X$, can it be shown that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\} \in X$ such that $x \not\in \{x_n\}$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$? More generally, I know that completeness implies every element of a complete space can be written as the limit of some sequence contained in the space, but how can this be shown?

Comment: Every discrete metric space is a counterexample. In general you are asking if a complete metric space has no isolated points. The answer is no, you can build many counterexamples.

Comment: It's true in any metric space that every element is the limit of some sequence. Completeness is quite a different kind of statement - it's about certain sequences being guaranteed to converge. The property "there is a sequence in $X \setminus \{x\}$ converging to $x$" is equivalent to $x$ being a non-isolated point. Every point being non-isolated neither implies nor is implied by completeness.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you, how can one see that every element in a metric space is the limit of some sequence?

Comment: That was in response to "More generally, I know that completeness implies every element of a complete space can be written as the limit of some sequence contained in the space". This is true for the trivial reason that $x$ is the limit of the constant sequence $(x)$. As I say in the rest of my comment, there is no implication between completeness and $x$ being the limit of a sequence in $X \setminus \{x\}$. The number of isolated points can be finite, infinite, cofinite, zero, or the whole space in both complete and incomplete metric spaces. Can you tell us what you think complete means?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I think of completeness as taking a metric space and adding to it all limits of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: That's a good mental picture! But I think perhaps you're leaning on your mental picture of "start with $\Bbb Q$ and complete it to get $\Bbb R$" too much. There are many metric spaces that look different - eg if you start with $\Bbb Z$, then adding limits of Cauchy sequences adds nothing, so you just get $\Bbb Z$ again. It is true that if $X$ is a metric space with no isolated points, then the completion of $X$ also has no isolated points. Is that perhaps the sort of fact you're looking for?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes that is what I was looking for, thank you for your help!

Comment: interesting...a question when the user has not showed any work gots a lot of attention, but other questions on feed with "basic questions" asking for help are downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The space which has only one point is a counterexample.